# Receiving HTML code in response to my token request

Tags: docusignapi

Using this info:

https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic xxxx

Note: (xxxx is my integrator_id:secret_key base 64 encoded, i didnt want to post the value publicly)

I do a post call using the following params in the body:

grant_type: 'authorization_code',
code:       '{The code returned from the /oauth/auth call}'

Instead of getting a json response, I get an HTML response that I can't seem to post in this message, because its too large.

I am completely stuck and can't finish my project because of this problem.

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of the call from Postman or any other Rest client, one thing I noticed, I hope it is a typo error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong host in calling the /oauth/token, you need to call
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token for Demo and
https://account.docusign.com/oauth/token for PROD

You should not call demo.docusign.net or www.docusign.com, these hosts are for rest of the API calls but not for OAUTH.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email-using-a-template

I am using "https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2/oauth/token". 

I worked around this problem for now using some code I found that accesses vi demo.docusign.com/resapi/v2, I am confused what endpoint to use. 

When I call envelopes for example. Which server is correct "https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2/" OR "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/"

Comment: Addition to last comment:

For reference: My work around I found was a ruby gem (See https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest.)

I am confused what endpoint to use. 

Note: Even though I found a work around, I still would like to resolve the original oauth problem

Comment: Hi Mike, the Ruby Gem code uses old way of OAUTH, in that you need to pass email and password in the body of the call, `grant_type=password&client_id=#{integrator_key}&username=#{email}&password=#{password}&scope=api`, DocuSign now does not recommend using it. We recommend to use below, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html

Comment: I fixed the host and unfortunately now I am getting an invalid grant error. 
My header is 
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
 'Authorization' =>  'Basic xxxxxxxxxx'
 
 My body is 
 
  "grant_type":   "authorization_code",
        "code":   xxxxxxxxx
  
  
I double checked to make sure Base64 code was correct. 

I double checked my code was correct.

Now I am Stuck again

Comment: The code which you get from DocuSign after redirection is only one time use, so you need to use it once and another thing is Authorization value should be Basic Base64 of IntegratorKey:SecretKey and a post call to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token (Demo Environment) and once you get code from DocuSign you need to paste it in the body after =    `grant_type=authorization_code&code=`. If you are following this then invalid_grant error will be fixed.